# How to compile atanks from windows?

Tags: c++, windows, compilation, allegro

I'm starting to learn C++ to make a game, I compiled some little programs and it worked fine to learn. Now I want to compile a game and learn how it was done.
The game I'm trying to compile is ATANKS (https://libregamewiki.org/Atanks).
First problem I have is the makefile contains an instruction on the target WINUSER that gives me error (it doesn't found the directory INSTALLDIR), I tried to compile manually entering SRC directory and run MAKE -f makefile.windows, it start to compile and stops with this error:

```
c:/tdm-gcc-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-min
gw32/bin/ld.exe: atanks.o: bad reloc address 0x20 in section `.data'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [../atanks.exe] Error 1
```

Because a comment in the file atanks.rc I asume this was writed using DEV-C++ but it hasn't the .DEV project file.
Some info:
I'm using windows 7 64 bits.
I have installed DEV-C++, but for my game I'm using CODEBLOCKS.
Installed TDM-GCC-4.8.1-3 and allegro-4.4.2-mingw-4.5.2
Installed make-3.81
The PATH variable is: PATH=c:\TDM-GCC-64\bin\;"c:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin\";

Other thing I tryed is making a CODEBLOCKS project, it seems to go but give me some errors too.

Thanks in advance and forgive me the bad english :)
(maybe someone can recommend me a forum to ask more, better if the language is spanish)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone on a IRC Channel help me to solve it, a little change on the makefile and use a 32 bit compiler instead 64 bit one was the solution.

Comment: What was that little change to the makefile?

Comment: Those two lines:
FLAGS += -DNEW_GAMELOOP -DDATA_DIR=\".\" -Wno-write-strings -DWIN32
LDFLAGS = -L../.. -lallegro-4.4.2-mt